# Find -regex is slower than find | grep

Tags: regex, bash, find, grep

I have a script which looks for a file using a regular expression. The code was the following:

```
find $dir | grep "$regex"
```

The script run a bit too slow and I want to optimise it. The search takes some time to perform and I would like to get better performance out of it. I've tried this attempt:

```
find $dir -regex ".*${regex}.*"
```

I was expecting slightly faster results as no extra process is created to parse the regular expression.

However the result was different and to my astonishment the command "find | grep" is faster than "find -regex" (although it takes more system time, as one would have expected)

I've timed this behaviour:

Find | grep result

```
real   0m12.467s
user   0m2.568s
sys    0m7.260s
```

Find -regex result

```
real   0m16.778s
user   0m6.772s
sys    0m6.380s
```

Do you have any idea why the find -regex solution is slower?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely because `grep` and its regex engine has been highly optimized over many years, since that's its only purpose ("do one thing and do it well").  I don't know what regex engine `find` uses, but it's evidently not as highly refined as `grep`'s, probably because it's a less-often-used secondary feature.

Also, if you are doing anything with this file list, you should really use a more whitespace-safe way of doing this. I don't think `grep` can take null-delimited input (though it can output it), so you should use `find [...] -regex [...] -print0` even though it's slower.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. In this use case I don't need the -print0, but it's a switch I often use. I'm getting the results of the find in Ruby and I split the string with "\n", thus unless there is a \n in the name, I should be fine.