# Finding all files with asterisks or dash character in them

Tags: unix, find

I want to do a search for all files in my system with special characters. Reason is that I moved from Linux to Mac and the exfat file format did not copy folder called e.g. "A*STAR presentation". So I want to manually find the non-copied files and folders. I suspect characters such as - may also not be supported?

Problem is that `*` is the wildcard character in the `find` function. So I am looking for a way to use `*` as a normal character.

```
find -name *'*'* ./ or something similar?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to

```
find . -name '*[\**]*'
```

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's faster to pipe `find` output to `grep` for [filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431331/find-regex-is-slower-than-find-grep) than using `-regex` option of `find`.  So, use this command for finding all files that have special characters `*` and/or `-`:

```
find $PWD | grep -E '[*-]+'
```

or, if you don't need the full path:

```
find . | grep -E '[*-]+'
```

---

These are the files I have in my test directory:

```
$ ls -1
*another
another normal
normal
special *
special -
very*good
```

Let's find the special ones:

```
$ find . | grep -E '[*-]+'
./*another
./special *
./special -
./very*good
```